# join alternate table per record based on value of field in primary table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an index table each record has a recordid and a datatype field
I also have 4 data tables all with identical fields.
How can I retrieve x records from index table and based on the value of datatype, join THAT record to the appropriate data table and return the whole lot in a single record set?
For example:
indexrec1 has recordid=12 and datatype=text and the rest of the fields will be from the text table corresponding to recordid=12 in the text table.
indexrec2 has recordid of 9 and datatype=image and the rest of the fields will be from the image table corresponding to recordid=9 in the image table.

1. Is this possible and if so, how do I do it.
2. If it is possible then will it be quicker than retrieving the records from the index table AND THEN doing a separate sql qry on the appropriate data table?

This will be run on an Apache server under PHP.
Please be gentle, I am NOT a MySQL expert - an "Idiots Guide" answer would be great if it is possible...

Comment: You can use `JOIN` to link the tables together.

Comment: Thanks Eric - I tried that and wound up with way too many fields in the returned record and far too much data. in addition, record 6 in one data table was not in any way associated to record 6 in another data table.
The resulting recordset would seriously impact the memory available on the server.

Comment: If your doing a `select * from` then it will return all the data from every table, if you list just the fields your interested in, this will be more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a query with joins to link every table you need

For example:

```
select rec1.indexrec1,rec2.* from rec1
inner join [text table] as rec2 on
rec1.indexrec1 = rec2.indexrec2
```

What am I doing? Well I´m showing the index from table `[rec1]` and all the columns in `[text table] as rec2` by linking them using the indexrec column through an inner join.

There is a catch though, using `inner join` will only show records that matches with this condition `rec1.indexrec1 = rec2.indexrec2`.

Depending in what you really need you can use diferent `Joins`

Read more about `join` in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: w3schools?  Friends don't let friends use w3schools; too much old and bogus stuff. Be careful.

Comment: You should use more conditions with a `where` if there are to many records or use other join methods, try `left join` or `right join`

Comment: Manuel - I think your suggestion has given me a workaround idea - I'll report back once I have tested it - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do a separate query with each table, and combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT *
FROM indexTable AS i
JOIN textTable AS t ON i.recordId = t.recordId
WHERE i.datatype = 'text' AND i.recordId = 12

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM indexTable AS i
JOIN imageTable AS im ON i.recordId = im.recordId
WHERE i.datatype = 'image' AND i.recordId = 12
```

Continue this pattern for all the types.

But if all the data tables have identical fields, why do you have them as separate tables?

Comment: Wont that result in a massive data set?
Point 2 is that the id in the index table refers to the id in the data table indicated by the datatype field in the index table.

Comment: If you're looking for a specific ID it won't be massive. I've added that to the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: The data being stored changes across the different tables. One table will have a "comment" field(type=test) while another does not need it so in the second table comment field is a char thus saving space and load time.
It also has something to do with a very processing intensive operation that I will need to do alter and I am trying to make that operation easier (and not time out on the browser)

Comment: I see -- they're not *really* identical, but you've made them identical so they can be used in a query like this.

Answer (score 0):

It does "work" but does not give the results expected.

I created an index table, a text table and a nums table - the latter 2 having the same field names.

Then I created 2 index records, one to access the record in the text table and one to access the record in the nums table. (creates a record in both text and nums)

Then I ran the following sql:

> SELECT `test_index`.`test_id`, `test_index`.`datatype`, `test_index`.`externalrecid`, `test_index`.`something`, `test_nums`.`rec_id`, `test_nums`.`datatype`, `test_nums`.`value1`, `test_nums`.`valu2`, `test_text`.`rec_id`, `test_text`.`datatype`, `test_text`.`value1`, `test_text`.`valu2` FROM `test_index` LEFT JOIN `test_nums` ON `test_nums`.`datatype`=`test_index`.`datatype` LEFT JOIN `test_text` ON `test_text`.`datatype`=`test_index`.`datatype`

[PHPMyAdmin results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snn8D.png)

Then I ran the same sql in a php script and print_r 'd the resulting rows and got this:

> Array ( [test_id] => 1 [datatype] => text [externalrecid] => 1 [something] => indextable [rec_id] => 1 [value1] => text value 1 [valu2] => text value 2 )
>
> Array ( [test_id] => 2 [datatype] => [externalrecid] => 1 [something] => should be nums [rec_id] => [value1] => [valu2] => )

As you can see, in the second array (record set) the values for the fields are missing.

I therefore conclude that the second value for a given field name overrides the first value and because of that I cannot use this method as it currently stands.

In the 2nd array dump, the values I need are in the first set of field names but they get overwritten by the NULL values of the 2nd set. NOT GOOD!!!

But on the bright side:

If I change the field names so that they are all unique across the secondary tables I will get all the fields from all the tables.

The better news is that all the unwanted fields, although present, have a NUL value and this means that the size (in bytes) of the whole record set will be greatly reduced and that was my original goal when I started.

My (home grown) template engine will need to be modified so as to test the value of the field BEFORE parsing the value into the template (a reduction of almost 75% in processing) and that should get everything sped up (my secondary goal)

Thanks to all who participated - hope that this helps someone else in the future - as I said up front, I am NOT a MySQL expert...